# Getting Intel Rapid Storage to work

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, intel-rst

This question is strongly related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/609392/intel-rapid-storage-refuses-to-work-no-button-in-srt-utility) one.
I experience the same problem. Unfortunately the proposed solution of removing the SSD disc (disc1) via disc manager gives the following error:
"Cannot delete an active system partition"
Which is weird, because I bought a new laptop, without an operating system and installed windows 7 on the HDD drive (which on the disc manager is disc0).
Does anybody know how to resolve this?

I would add a picture of the disc manager, but I can't (lack of reputation).

Comment: Start over from scratch and reinstall...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what caused the problem in the first place. The boot order during installation (form USB) was set as follows.

- USB Disc
- mSATA SSD
- Local Hard Drive
- ... (other)

Which apparently caused the system to install boot.ini on the SSD regardless which disc I chose to install the system on.
I changed the boot order to:

- USB Disc
- Local Hard Drive
- ...

and did a fresh install, during which I removed the SSD disc (not physically of course, but in the installation menu).

I hope this helps someone some day.